# How to query the first id of a duplicated data

Tags: php

I have a table that have duplicated data in the table, I want to select the duplicated data and use the first ID of the data for all the duplicated data

```
Table1
id    |     name    | Number    |
001   |     amanda  |  457      |
002   |     amanda  |  457      |
003   |     jose    |  458      |
004   |     jose    |  458      |
005   |     past    |  459      |
006   |     past    |  459      |


Now I want the duplicate to have the same `id` for all the duplicated data

What I expect

Table2
id    |     name    | Number    |
001   |     amanda  |  457      |
001   |     amanda  |  457      |
003   |     jose    |  458      |
003   |     jose    |  458      |
005   |     past    |  459      |
005   |     past    |  459      |
```

I want a query that can do this grouping; here is what I have tried:

```
  $query ="SELECT
            id,
            name,
            number
        FROM
            `Table`  ";

$result=$db->query($query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $id=$row['iD']; 
        $number=$row['number']; 

     $ss="UPDATE `Table` SET `id`='$id' WHERE `id` =$id";
        $e=$db->query($ss);


}
```

I know this is wrong. I would be grateful if somebody can help me get it right. Thanks.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service, show us what you have tried.

Comment: That `id` column must be unique I think, why you want to do this ?

Comment: the id is a composite key

Answer (score 0):

You need following things to solve your problem.

1.You need to get first id and older id.
2.Update older with first id.

I updated your query to get first and older id.

```
$query ="SELECT 
    DT2.id as olderID,
    DT1.id as newID, 
    DT1.name, 
    DT1.Number
FROM 
    duplicate_table DT1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        name, 
        Number 
    FROM 
        duplicate_table 
    GROUP BY 
        name, 
        id 
    ORDER BY 
        name, 
        id ASC 
) DT2 ON ( DT2.name=DT1.name)
WHERE 
    DT1.id > DT2.id
GROUP BY 
    DT1.name, 
    DT1.id 
ORDER BY 
    DT1.name, 
    DT1.id DESC ";

$result=$db->query($query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $olderID=$row['olderID']; 
        $newID=$row['newID']; 
        $id=$row['iD']; 
        $number=$row['number']; 
     $ss="UPDATE `Table` SET `id`='$olderID' WHERE `id` =$newID";
        $e=$db->query($ss);
}
```